# AngularJS =?bind not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've lost my bearings with regards to why I can't pass updates to my directives.

What I'm trying to accomplish with the following piece of code is to be able to set focus on  by pressing a button. The problem is however that the "focus" binding on drInput only ever is set when the directive have loaded when it should change whenever it changes in drWrap. How come and how do I get around this?

And now, ladies and gentlemen, I present to you: THE CODE!

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <dr-wrap></dr-wrap>
</div>
```

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('drWrap', function($timeout) {
        return {
            scope: {
                focus: '=?bind'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<div><button ng-click="openSearch()">focus</button><dr-input focus="focusSearch" /></div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                                    scope.openSearch = function(){
                    $timeout(function(){
                        scope.focusSearch = true
                        alert('scope.focusSearch 2 = ' + scope.focusSearch)
                    }, 1000)
                }
            }
        };
    })
        .directive('drInput', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                focus: '=?bind'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<input type="test" focus-me="{{ focus }}" />',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                scope.$watch('focus', function(value){
                        if(value != undefined){
                        scope.focus = value
                        alert('scope.focus = ' + scope.focus)
                    }
                })
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('focusMe', function(value){
                    if ((value === true) || (value == 'true')) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            element[0].focus()
                            scroll(element[0])
                        })
                    } else {
                        element[0].blur()
                    }
                    })
            }
        }
    }])
```

And the FIDDLE!
https://jsfiddle.net/L56rdqLp/168/

Comment: I am in front of your jsfiddle but... what do you mean with "The problem is however that the binding only ever is set when the directive have loaded. How come and how do I get around this?"

Comment: I have elaborated. Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `scope: { focus: '=?bind' }`, this means that the attribute name should be `bind` but not `focus`, so the template of `drWrap` should look like:

```
template: '<div><button ng-click="openSearch()">focus</button><dr-input bind="focusSearch" /></div>'
```

Add [`ngBlur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) event handler to `drInput` directives `input` like:

```
template: '<input type="test" focus-me="{{ focus }}" ng-blur="focus = false"/>',
```

to change the model to false, when input has lost its focus.

Here is [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L56rdqLp/170/).